# Bonobo Installation - Server Error in Application : Exceptionless.Mvc

Tags: git, bonobo, exceptionless

I'm trying to install Bonobo 5.2.0. on Windows Server 2008R2 under IIS7.  After installation I'm receiving this error:

```
Server Error in '/Bonobo' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'Exceptionless.Mvc' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Exceptionless.Mvc' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 


An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Exceptionless.Mvc' could not be loaded.

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.


Stack Trace: 

[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Exceptionless.Mvc' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName) +70
System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +39
System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +37
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +65
System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase) +38

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'Exceptionless.Mvc' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase) +359
System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, Boolean checkAptcaBit) +19
System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry.SecureGetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement) +39
System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry..ctor(String name, String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement) +42
System.Web.HttpApplication.BuildIntegratedModuleCollection(List`1 moduleList) +160
System.Web.HttpApplication.GetModuleCollection(IntPtr appContext) +950
System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +82
System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Exceptionless.Mvc' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9952212
System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

The folder has been turned into an application, I've installed and registered MVC4.0, Authentication has been set accordingly... what am I missing?

I haven't been able to find anything on the issue anywhere.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that I'm trying to place it on a web server that already has an application running on it. I'm assuming the global web.config that was set up for the initial site is interfering with this installation.

It's not much of a resolution or answer to this problem, but at least I know why it's happening.

Solution: Move Bonobo to another server.

Comment: I work on the exceptionless project. From the sound of it, it sounds like the Exceptionless dependencies weren't placed in the bin folder. Did your deployment copy all the files?